# How to save and serve multiple HTML snippets

Tags: html, json, angular

I have an Angular app with a sidebar and a content area, where different HTML-code shall be displayed. For now I saved the HTML-code for every topic in a JSON-file with the topics headlines, which is opened with the URL-parameter-values.
I searched for possible solutions, but I'm not sure what is best practice. I want to pass the HTML-code with the URL-parameter-values and display it in a router-outlet in the content area. But I realized that JSON is not very usable for longer HTML-snippets because of its syntax. I could create an HTML-file for every single content page, but then I will end up with really many files (I want to create some course structure for my pupils). I also thought about creating single Angular components for every single page, which would end in the same problem, beside the fact that you have to import everything in single components since Angular 17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice would typically be to simply create a separate .html file for each component, as well as separate .css and .ts files.

Typically the idea is to encapsulate a component into its own set of files for clarity, as that set of files should only have code that deals with that one specific component. You can see this in action in the [Angular tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/tour-of-heroes/toh-pt1).